# Retrieving the application-wide container in web api

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm trying to solve a problem I have with asynchronous event-based rest services. I have services that generate events in the application, and those events are handled asynchronouly. The problem I have is my linq to sql data contexts are disposed by then, because of autofac's lifetime scopes.

I found a website that had a solution for it and it involved getting the application wide container. He got it like so :

```
var accessor = ((IContainerProviderAccessor) HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance);
return accessor.ContainerProvider.ApplicationContainer;
```

However, I can't import IContainerProviderAccessor, which seems to be in autofac's mvc integration assembly. How can I translate this code for web api.

Answer (score 0):

`IContainerProviderAccessor` is no longer supported. *Autofac* now use the [`IDependencyResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver) of ASP.net MVC

If you want to access the resolver you can use the [`DependencyResolver.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver.current(v=vs.118).aspx) property of ASP.net MVC.

```
YourDbContext yourDbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<YourDbContext>();
```

Another solution would be to inject `Func<Owned<YourDbContext>>`, it will act as a factory. Each time you need a `DbContext` inside an API method you will be able to invoke it Autofac will instanciate a new one.